# Provider 'UserApi' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my factory..

```
var UserService = angular.module('UserService', []);

UserService.factory('UserApi', function ($http) {
var baseUrl = "http://localhost:59844/api";
var UserApi = {};

    UserApi.getUsers = function () {
        return $http.get(baseUrl + '/UserLogins');
    };
});
```

And in my controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute','UserService']);
myApp.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, UserApi) {
getUsers();
function getUsers(){
    UserApi.getUsers.success(function (users) {
            $scope.users = users;
        }).error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = "Couldn't load data";
        })
    }
});
```

It seems UserApi doesn't return any value. But  cannot get it why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the service object also

```
var UserService = angular.module('UserService', []);

UserService.factory('UserApi', function ($http) {
    var baseUrl = "http://localhost:59844/api";
    var UserApi = {};

    UserApi.getUsers = function () {
        return $http.get(baseUrl + '/UserLogins');
    };

    return UserApi;
});
```

Comment: It worked. Now i am facing problem in the controller. It says "UserApi.getUsers.success is not a function".

Comment: @JaowatRaihan the $http returens a promise, use "then" instead of success